# Get the selector of a .delegate

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In this code I need to get the *DOM object* that is `.tabs` the original selector that the delegate is wired up against.

```
$(".tabs").delegate("li:not(.selected) a", "click", function () {
//  ^    
//  |
//  +-----------i need to get this dom object   
    var selector = $(this).selector; // <---- returns an empty string ?
    return false;
});
```

How to determine what `.tabs` is and access the object?

Comment: Why do you need the selector?

Comment: The selector or even whatever. As long as I can access .tabs in an 'anonymous' way, And perhaps a better solution than parent-traversal from the li a. There are different tabs on the page, that need to be handled a bit different.

Comment: The reason why `.selector` won't work here is because you are trying to access it off a jQuery object that wraps around `this`, a DOM object, instead of a selector string.

Comment: You could hardcode it but I guess this is not what you want.... does `.tabs` select multiple or just one element? Do you want to get all DOM elements or just the one for which the event was triggered (by its descendants)? Unfortunately, jQuery seems to adjust the `event` object so that `event.currentTarget` does not work :-/

Comment: @BoltLock indeed, that is a part of my problem here ;)

Comment: @Felix, it selects multiple instances of .tabs on the page, (sorry for the naming)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until someone finds a smarter way, a workaround could be to attach an event handler to the selected elements themselves:

```
$('.tabs').click(function(event) {
    event.root = this; // or whatever name suits you best
});

$(".tabs").delegate("li:not(.selected) a", "click", function (event) {
    // event.root contains the DOM element
});
```

jQuery guarantees  that event handlers are executed in the order they are attached.

Or you don't use `delegate` at all and make the selector test yourself (*this is probably the best solution*):

```
$('.tabs').click(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).is("li:not(.selected) a")) {
        // this refers to the .tab DOM element
        // event.target refers to the originally clicked element
    }
});
```

---

**Update:**

The original `Event` object is available via `event.originalEvent`. So you could do:

```
$(".tabs").delegate("li:not(.selected) a", "click", function (event) {
    var dom = event.originalEvent.currentTarget;
});
```

**But it seems `currentTarget` is only supported in IE9 and there is no alternative in lower IE versions**.

So the most cross-browser compatible solutions are still the ones above.

Answer (score 3):

With the `.on()` method, you can access the delegated target by passing the event object to your function and accessing its `delegateTarget` property.

Example:

```
$('.foo').on('click', 'a', function(ev) {
  // this is the .foo element for this anchor
  console.log(ev.delegateTarget);
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/corydorning/ZzADh/